# ggplot put a plot inside of another plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that `grid.arrange` allows me to put two, or more, graphs beside each other with ggplot. How do I put a graph inside of another graph? If you can remember back to the 1990's this used to be called PIP Picture-In-Picture. Let's use this as our reproducible data.

```
library(ggplot2)
(plotx <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point())
```

In case you're not clear on what I want I'll try and ASCII it out below:

```
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                   ---------   |
|                   | plotx |   |
|                   ---------   |
|      same plotx               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`egg` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/). There is a function called `annotation_custom` that you might find useful. An example would be `library(egg); plotx + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(plotx), xmin = 4.5, xmax = 6.5, ymin = 25, ymax = 40)`